# Probability of the union of $3$ events?

Tags: probability

I need some clarification for why the probability of the union of three events is equal to the right side in the following:

$$P(E\cup F\cup G)=P(E)+P(F)+P(G)-P(E\cap F)-P(E\cap G)-P(F\cap G)+P(E\cap F\cap G)$$

**What I don't understand** is, why is the last term(intersection of all) added back just once, when it was subtracted three times as it appears from a Venn Diagram?

Here on page 3, this is explained but not in enough details that I can understand it:
http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m19w03/public_html/Section6-2.pdf

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One of the axioms of probability is that if $A_1, A_2, \dots$ are disjoint, then

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(A_i\right)\text{.}\tag{*}
\end{align}$$

It so happens that this is also true if you have a finite number of disjoint events. If you're interested in more detail, consult a measure-theoretic probability  textbook.

Let's motivate the proof for the probability of the union of three events by using this axiom to prove the probability of the union of two events.

> **Theorem**. For two events $A$ and $B$, $\mathbb{P}\left(A \cup B\right) = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$.
>
> **Proof**. Write $$A \cup B = \left(A \cap B\right) \cup \left(A \cap B^{c}\right) \cup \left(A^{c} \cap B\right)\text{.}$$ Notice also that $A = \left(A \cap B^{c}\right) \cup\left(A \cap B\right)$ and $B = \left(B \cap A^{c}\right) \cup \left(A \cap B\right)$.
>
> [image]
>
> Since we have written $A$ and $B$ as disjoint unions of sets, applying (*) in the finite case, we have that 
>   $$\begin{align}
> \mathbb{P}\left(A\right) &= \mathbb{P}\left(A \cap B^{c}\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(A \cap B\right) \\
> \mathbb{P}\left(B\right) &= \mathbb{P}\left(B \cap A^{c}\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(A \cap B\right) \\
> \end{align}$$
>   Similarly, since $A \cup B = \left(A \cap B\right) \cup \left(A \cap B^{c}\right) \cup \left(A^{c} \cap B\right)$ is a disjoint union of sets,
>   $$\begin{align}
> \mathbb{P}\left(A \cup B\right) &= \mathbb{P}\left[ \left(A \cap B\right) \cup \left(A \cap B^{c}\right) \cup \left(A^{c} \cap B\right) \right] \\
> &= \overbrace{\mathbb{P}\left(A \cap B\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(A \cap B^{c}\right)}^{\mathbb{P}(A)} + \mathbb{P}\left(A^{c} \cap B\right) \\
> &= \mathbb{P}\left(A\right) + \overbrace{\mathbb{P}\left(A^{c} \cap B\right)}^{\mathbb{P}(B)-\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)} \\
> &= \mathbb{P}\left(A\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(B\right) - \mathbb{P}\left(A \cap B\right)\text{. } \square
> \end{align}$$

---

Now, armed with the result that we proved in the previous theorem, we can now prove the result for the probability of the union of three events.

> **Theorem**. $\mathbb{P}\left(A \cup B \cup C\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(A\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(B\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(C\right) - \mathbb{P}\left(A \cap B\right) - \mathbb{P}\left(A \cap C\right) - \mathbb{P}\left(B \cap C\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(A \cap B \cap C\right)$
>
> **Proof**. Since $A \cup B \cup C = \left(A \cup B\right) \cup C$, by the previous theorem, 
>   $$\begin{align}
> \mathbb{P}\left(A \cup B \cup C\right) &= \mathbb{P}((A \cup B)\cup C) \\
> &= \overbrace{\mathbb{P}\left(A \cup B\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(C\right) - \mathbb{P}\left[\left(A \cup B\right) \cap C\right]}^{\text{applying the previous theorem to }\mathbb{P}((A \cup B)\cup C)} \\
> &= \overbrace{\mathbb{P}\left(A\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(B\right) - \mathbb{P}\left(A \cap B\right)}^{\mathbb{P}\left(A \cup B\right)  \text{ from the previous theorem}} + \mathbb{P}\left(C\right) - \mathbb{P}\left[\overbrace{\left(A \cap C\right) \cup \left(B \cap C\right)}^{(A \cup B)\cap C\text{ (distributive property of sets)}}\right] \\
> &= \mathbb{P}\left(A\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(B\right) - \mathbb{P}\left(A \cap B\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(C\right) \\
> &\qquad- \overbrace{\Big[\mathbb{P}\left(A \cap C\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(B \cap C\right) - \mathbb{P}\left[\left(A \cap C\right) \cap \left(B \cap C\right) \right]\Big]}^{\text{applying the previous theorem to }\mathbb{P}\left(\left(A \cap C\right) \cup \left(B \cap C\right)\right)}\text{,}
> \end{align}$$
>   and since $\left(A \cap C\right) \cap \left(B \cap C\right) = A \cap B \cap C$, the result is proven. $\square$

Comment: While I didn't ask for an analytic clarification explicitly, I've been trying to do this during the past 2 days, so I thank you for this. But how did you turn `P[(A∪B)∩C]` to `P[(A∩C)∪(B∩C)]`?

Comment: That is the distributive property of sets, usually proven in a Real Analysis class. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra . Note that $\left(A \cup B\right) \cap C = C \cap \left(A \cup B\right)$ as you look through this link.

Comment: I'll go with this answer because it helped me in several ways.

Comment: To comment on why `P[ (A ∪ B) ∩ C ]` is able to become `P[ (A ∩ C) ∪ (B ∩ C) ]`, try drawing out a Venn Diagram to understand visually what's happening here.

Comment: @Clarinetist amazing drawing you got there

Answer (score 11):

[image: 3 sets]

Since in this formula you add this part 3 times(in the first 3 terms) and subtract it also 3 times(in the next 3 terms), you have to add it again.

Answer (score 8):

An interesting way to find the answer is by looking at the following Venn diagram:

[image: Venn diagram: Union of 3 events]

The numbers in red indicate how many times a certain section has been included/added by using $P(A) + P(B) + P(C)$. The sections which feature ***more than once*** must be subtracted from the former to avoid double-counting and obtain the final answer.

1. The blank sections are added once. $\implies$ *No subtraction required*.
2. The dashed (||) sections represent $P(A \cap B \cap C^c)$, $P(A \cap B^c \cap C)$, and $P(A^c \cap B \cap C)$. Each term is included **twice**, $\implies$ hence each must be subtracted **once**.
3. The dotted (::) section represents $P(A \cap B \cap C)$. Appears ***thrice*** $\implies$ must subtracted ***twice***.

This yields:

$$P(A \cup B \cup C ) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B \cap C^c) - P(A \cap B^c \cap C) - P(A^c \cap B \cap C) - 2P(A \cap B \cap C).$$

Observing from the figure that:
$$P(A \cap B \cap C^c) = P(A \cap B) - P(A \cap B \cap C),$$
$$P(A \cap B^c \cap C) = P(A \cap C) - P(A \cap B \cap C),$$
$$P(A^c \cap B \cap C) = P(B \cap C) -P(A \cap B \cap C),$$

Replacing these values in the above results in the final formula, given by:
$$P(A \cup B \cup C ) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B) -  P(A \cap C) - P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C).$$

Comment: I finally understood it, thanks!