# Proof of probability of union of three events

Tags: probability

[image: Proof of Union]

I was thinking that I would draw Venn Diagrams that indicate that the union of three events equals the sum of the three events minus the intersections shown in the equation. Would this suffice as a proof? It seems entirely too simple and I have a hard time believing that there isn't a different way of proving this equation.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669249/probability-of-the-union-of-3-events?rq=1) might probably interest you :)

Comment: To reconcile the two formulas (in this question and in [that one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/669249/139123)), it helps to remember that $P(EF) = P(EFG) + P(EFG^\complement)$.

Comment: The link posted only shows a proof of the union of three events and the sum of the three independent events minus their intersection. The one I posted is a little different and I'm stuck on how I can work my formula into that proof.